# How to float div in bottom left over image?

Tags: html, css, nested

I need to float a div over an image in the bottom left corner.

I'm banging my head over this one. I'm sure this is simple, but I just can't figure it out.

Here is as far as I managed to get.

http://jsfiddle.net/pauleh/6GXFK/

```
.group li{
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;  
}
.group li img {
    display: block;
}
.group li span {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 25px 0 0 25px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ff0000;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="group">
    <ul>
       <li><img src="http://placehold.it/196x155"/><span></span></li>
       <li><img src="http://placehold.it/196x155"/><span></span></li>
       <li><img src="http://placehold.it/196x155"/><span></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Floats not necessary. Use positioning. The span gets absolute, with left and bottom set to zero. Then the parent li gets relative:

```
.group li {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    position:relative;
}
.group li img {
    display: block;
}
.group li span {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 25px 0 0 25px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ff0000;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6GXFK/2/)**